# Lower bound on energy is potential minimum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, operators, potential-energy, hamiltonian

Suppose we have a particle of mass $m$ that is in an eigenstate $|\psi\rangle$ of the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}=\hat{T}+\hat{V}$, where $\hat{T}$ is the kinetic energy operator and $\hat{V}=V(\hat{r})$ is the potential energy operator. **If the potential has lower bound $V_0$, then is it necessary for the energy eigenvalue $E$ of $|\psi\rangle$ to be greater than $V_0$?** Classically this is true, since we regard negative kinetic energy as physically unrealizable/meaningless. However, I don't know if I can necessarily say the same in the quantum case. For example, what I'm tempted to do is write

$$\langle\psi | \hat{T}|\psi \rangle = \langle\psi | E-\hat{V}|\psi\rangle$$

and say "If $E<V_0$, then the RHS is necessarily negative, implying the LHS is as well, which we will regard as physically meaningless. If $E=V_0$, then $|\psi\rangle$ is trivial.", but I'm not sure if that's right.

Confused by that, I then wanted to show that, if $E< V_0$, then a non-trivial $|\psi\rangle$ is non-normalizable. However, I'm not entirely sure how to do this.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Oh sorry no, after looking a bit more into it I think your answer is fine. I just always wait a while before accepting an answer. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The operator $\hat T$ is positive definite (a.e), which means that for most kets $|\varphi\rangle\neq 0$ you have
$$
\langle \varphi|\hat T|\varphi\rangle>0
$$

One way to see this is that $\hat T$ is quadratic in $\hat P$, which is itself self-adjoint. Therefore
$$
\langle\varphi|\hat T|\varphi\rangle=\frac{1}{2m}\langle\varphi|\hat P^2|\varphi\rangle=\frac{1}{2m}\big|\big|\hat P|\varphi\rangle\big|\big|^2>0
$$

Alternatively, we know that $\hat T$ is proportional to the Laplacian $-\Delta$, which is positive-definite (a.e.), for example see [The minus Laplacian operator is positive definite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167379/the-minus-laplacian-operator-is-positive-definite).

With this, it is easy to see that
$$
E=\langle\varphi|\hat T+\hat V|\varphi\rangle\ge\langle\varphi|\hat V|\varphi\rangle\ge V_0\langle\varphi|\varphi\rangle=V_0
$$

Comment: Sorry for being late but why does $||\hat{P}|\varphi\rangle||>0$ hold a.e.?

Comment: @test123 Because $||\cdot||$ is a norm, it is positive definite. It is strictly positive unless the argument is the zero vector.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but this would imply $\hat{P}|\psi\rangle\neq 0$ a.e. so $\hat{P}$ is a.e. injective. Is this perhaps some theorem from functional analysis?

Comment: @test123 By $\hat P|\psi\rangle\neq0$ a.e. I mean that, for most kets $|\psi\rangle$, the ket $\hat P|\psi\rangle$ is non-zero. This is not any deep theorem, just the statement that most functions are not constant.

Comment: I'm very sorry for bothering you with this but my point is exactly that I just don't see why $\hat{P}|\psi\rangle$ should be non-zero almost everywhere. That's what I was referring to

Comment: @test123 I think you are expecting a deeper point than the one I am trying to make. Pick a random function. What is the probability that it is the constant function? The answer is zero. Most functions are not even continuous, let alone constant!