# Why must normalisable eigenfunctions have $E > V_{min}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, potential-energy

I have read normalisable eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian operator.
$$\hat{H}\phi = E\phi$$
If $\phi$ is to be normalisable we must have $E > V_{min}$

Why is this?

Comment: Do you know what the energies are for the Hydrogen atom wavefunctions? Are they normalisable?

Comment: Where did you read this? It's not true.

Comment: @Javier I have corrected the question, within the context that I read it originally $V_{min} = 0$ so they just said $E > 0$ but they meant $E > V_{min}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lower bound on energy is potential minimum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/245323/)

Answer (score 0):

It really is 'just mathematics'.

The solutions of the Time Independent Schrödinger Equation $\hat{H}\psi = E\psi$ are such that the lowest allowed energy level ($E_1$) is **always non-zero**.

It's a property that distinguishes quantum systems sharply from Classical systems.

Please note that the OP altered his question substantially since this answer was formulated.

Comment: But you could always add a constant to the Hamiltonian which could result in a zero ground state energy, no?

Comment: @Jakob No, I don't think so. At least for bound states, $E_1>0$, no matter what the Hamiltonian (potential well) is.

Comment: As far as I know, the Hamiltonian is required to be bounded from below (such that there exists a finite ground state energy). Adding a constant won't change the physics but shifts the spectrum such that E_1=0 (for example).

Comment: @Jakob I think you're wrong. Do you have a example/reference for your assertion?

Comment: I don't have a source at hand at the moment. But maybe you could argue, prove or provide a source for your assertion? Why do you think we are not allowed to shift the spectrum by a constant?

Comment: Afaik you can shift any observable by a constant without affecting it's legitimacy. The identity is Hermitian so you're not going to lose the most important property. It is common for instance in deriving the uncertainty relation for two operators to shift them by a constant so that their mean is zero.

Comment: @Gert  (this may not be the most rigorous proof, but anyway): Take any Hamiltonian which satisfies $\hat{H} |\phi_i\rangle = E_i\, |\phi_i\rangle$ with $E_i$ ordered increasingly. The Hamiltonian $\hat{h} \equiv \hat{H}-E_1$ fulfillls $\hat{h}|\phi_i\rangle = (E_i-E_1)|\phi_i\rangle$. Note that $(E_i-E_1) \geq 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: @Jakob My references are of course tonnes of derivations of the energy spectrum of Q systems with known analytical solutions. If you simple shift the energy abcissa up or down you don't actually solve anything. An equivalent Classical system, using that same energy abcissa, would then have a non-zero lowest energy!

Comment: @Jakob And that would not be incorrect but why do it when really it will confuse lots of people.

Comment: @Gert What do you mean? What is not incorrect? I just wanted to make clear that $E \neq 0$ must not hold true, in general.

Comment: @Jakob This is becoming 'how many angels on a pin'? Have the last word by all means. Energy is relative to some reference point, no dispute here. Have a nice day now.