# Minimum energy eigenvalue

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation, potential-energy, ground-state

Why is the energy eigenvalue is always greater than minimum potential for a particle moving in a certain potential?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lower bound on energy is potential minimum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/245323/)

Comment: It's an exact duplicate.